# Jetpack compose How to solve Unsolved reference: colors in MaterialTheme.colors

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm starting learning jetpack compose, I'm trying to follow the tutorials shown here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial?hl=es-419

But in the part https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial?hl=es-419#color it says to use: "MaterialTheme.colors" to set the colors of the elements, the problem is that my new and empty project displays:

[image]

"Unsolved reference: colors"

I have added:

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.1.1'
```

But I don't know how to have access to that element. How can I solved?

Answer (score 2):

`MaterialTheme.colors` is refering the [androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/MaterialTheme) class, not [androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/MaterialTheme), which does not have the `colors` property.

You can write `MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background` instead when using Material3

Answer (score 1):

You can opt for colorScheme of Material3 as suggested by @Ricky Mo

And if you still want to use `MaterialTheme.colors.background` then you need to update your import, i.e., replace `import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme` with `import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme`

Answer (score 1):

In material3, you must use this method to call the colors

```
MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
```

You can also add your own colors to the theme like this :

```
val ColorScheme.topAppbarColor: Color
@Composable
get() = Color.Black
```

And use this method to handle colors in dark theme

```
val ColorScheme.topAppbarColor: Color
@Composable
get() = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) Color.Black else Purple40
```